# Able to run Python code with Unicode string in Eclipse, but getting UnicodeEncodeError when running via command line or Idle.

Tags: python, eclipse, unicode, pydev

I've experienced this a lot, where I'll decode/encode some string of Unicode in Eclipse (PyDev), and it runs fine and how I expected, but then when I launch the same script from the command line (for example) instead, I'll get encoding errors.

Is there any simple explanation for this? Is Eclipse doing something to the Unicode/manipulating it in some different way?

EDIT:

Example:

```
value = u'\u2019'.decode( 'utf-8', 'ignore' )
return value
```

This works in Eclipse (PyDev) but not if I run it in Idle or on the command line.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 135: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Never `encode` when you `print` -- let it be done automatically. Then it will "just work" as Python will detect your encoding, as long as the terminal encoding is something that can render all unicode code points. If you tell us what your terminal / os are, we can tell you how to set that.

Comment: @agf It has nothing to do with printing though... the errors are occurring because I've got to 'translate' some text into utf-8 for it to be processed by another library, and the text I'm receiving isn't really "uniform" sometimes I get ascii, sometimes other types of unicode... I've been doing "text.decode( 'utf-8', 'ignore' )... is there a 'better' way to approach this?

Comment: I think we'll need to see example code that exhibits your problem.

Comment: do you have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your scripts?

Comment: @agf That would just be necessary if I was writing unicode character inside the code of my script...? which I'm not.

Comment: I was just making sure the strings you were translating weren't literals.

Comment: @wberry I added a very simple example.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that it probably SHOULDN'T work... but I'm still curious as to why it does in Eclipse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
value = u'\u2019'.decode( 'utf-8', 'ignore' )
```

Byte strings are DECODED into Unicode strings.

Unicode strings are ENCODED into byte strings.

So if you say `someunicodestring.decode`, it tries to coerce the Unicode string to a byte string, in order to be able to decode it (back to Unicode!). Being an implicit conversion, this encoding step will plump for the default encoding, which may differ between different environments, and is likely to be the ‘safe’ value `ascii`, which will certainly produce the error you mention as ASCII can't contain the character U+2019. It's almost never a good idea to rely on the default encoding.

So it doesn't make sense to try to `decode` a Unicode string. I'm pretty sure you mean:

```
value = u'\u2019'.encode('utf-8')
```

(`ignore` is redundant for encoding to UTF-8 as there is no character that this encoding can't represent.)

Comment: My issues comes in that where I'm using "u'\u2019'" in my example, I actually have some 'input' that is not always Unicode and not Always a byte string.. Which is why I did the .decode statement. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you could have either, usually you'd sniff it manually, eg. `if isinstance(s, unicode): s= s.encode('utf-8')` if you always want bytes, or `if isinstance(s, str): s= s.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')` if you always want Unicode.

Comment: Wow, that's really silly of me.. it didn't occur to me that "isinstance(s, unicode)" would work for any sort of unicode. Thank you for answering my question as well as fixing my underlying problem!

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to add why it worked on PyDev: it has a special sitecustomize that'll customize python through sys.setdefaultencoding to use the encoding of the PyDev console.

Note that the response from bobince is correct, if you have a unicode string, you have to use the encode() method to transform it into a proper string (you'd use decode if you had a string and wanted to transform it into a unicode).